# C++ array declare issue

Tags: c++, arrays

This code is giving me segfault :

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(int argc,char** argv[]){  

int ar[20000000];  

return 0;  

}
```

But if I reduce the size of array by 0 - then its fine. Am I exceeding the max size? What if I want to store that amount of integers? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably has to do with the fact that you're trying to allocate over 70 megabytes of data on the stack. Windows has a default stack size of 1 megabyte per thread IIRC. Try allocating it on the free-store with `new`, like so:

```
int* ar = new int[20000000];
```

and when you're done using it, `delete[]` it:

```
delete[] ar;
```

Comment: What makes you think it's 70 megabytes? It doesn't say that an int is 32 bits in the C/C++ standard.

Answer (score 3):

You got **stack overflow** :D A real one.

Allocate the memory on the heap, using `new`

```
int* ar = new int[ 20000000 ];
// do stuff with ar
delete[] ar; // do **not** forget about this
```

Answer (score 1):

the declaration of `int ar[20000000]` on the stack, takes appx 70MB+ (76.2939453MB) of memory... maybe you run out of space?

Use `new` to allocate on the heap.

Comment: 76.2939453 megabytes in fact.

Comment: 76.2939453 mebibytes (MiB), but 80 megabytes (MB).

Answer (score 1):

You may be exceeding the size allowed by the stack frame, which is enforced by your compiler. If you were to allocate the space dynamically, e.g.:

```
int array = new int[SIZE]
```

you would be limited by your OS and hardware rather than your compiler. (This is because dynamically allocating memory stores it on the heap, whereas a locally declared variable is stored on the stack, which has a stricter size limitation.)

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, 4 million is the limit

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to allocate this array on the stack, you can.  You just need to increase the stack size.  You don't say what compiler / linker you are using, but instructions for Visual Studio C++ are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx and other environments should have similar options.